# Azure Data Factory Mapping Data Flows VS SSIS

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory, dataflow

Its not really a coding problem so I hope its fine to ask here, otherwise I will just delete my post.

We have recently moved to the cloud and are trying out ADF data flows.I have expected it to be a bit more efficient. However, I don't really understand currently how are those superior to the SSIS packages. I have tried playing around with different settings and so far it appears to me as slower( cluster has to start up ) and more expensive solution. So now I am kind of in doubt whether just to leave my SSIS packages in there and trigger them from ADF pipelines or actually re-write them to data flows. The only pro that I see for now is that data flows could be more intuitive for non-technical people.

So I would be grateful if someone could explain to me "when" it's a right thing to actually use them ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How many packages do you have? How frequently do they run? How long? How complex are they (are you using scripts and custom components)? Are your data sources on-premises or in cloud? How long will they stay that way? Is this a PoC to get into Azure? There are many questions. If you take an ELT approach (load data into a database and transform it there with sql scripts) then you don't have to use mapping data flows, you can just use basic ADF

Comment: Hi,any updates here?Does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it all depends on your real scenario.

SSIS is SQL Server Integration Services and is part of the SQL Server product distribution, has been around since 2005 as SSIS and before that as DTS.

ADF mapping data flows, Cloud-based PaaS service for data integration.

Both can be used to integrate and transform data across on-prem and cloud data stores. However, SSIS is built primarily as an on-prem service while ADF has a scale-out data movement service in Azure.

You can lift & shift SSIS jobs into the cloud using ADF or build new ETL jobs in ADF as Cloud-first jobs.

More clues,please refer to this case:[Azure Data Factories vs SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985352/azure-data-factories-vs-ssis)